# Drupal site: mysql queries not closing and entry resource limit reached

Tags: mysql, drupal, cpanel

I have a drupal site (castlehillbasin.co.nz) that has a small number of users. Over the last few days it has suddenly hit the "entry processes limit" continually. 
My host provider has shown me that there are many open queries that are sleeping, so are not getting closed correctly. They have advised "to contact a web-developer and check the website codes to see why the databases queries are not properly closing. You will need to optimize the database and codes to resolve the issue". (their words)
I have not made any changes or updates prior to the problem starting. I also have a duplicate on my home server that does not have this issue. The host uses cpanel and I can not see these 'sleeping' processes through mysql queries.
Searching is not turning up many good solutions, except raising the entry process limit (which is 20) and the host will not do that.

So I am a little stumped as to how to resolve the issue, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have answered it myself. I got temporary ssh access and inspected live queries.
It was the Flickr module and the getimagesize() call timing out (which takes 2 minutes). Turns out it only uses this call for non-square image requests, so I have just displayed square images for now.

In progress issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2547171